# How can I uninstall my office add in?

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office

I developed an office add in and a setup application, but after I install it on my computer, and then I uninstall it, it seems everything is OK.

But when I want to reinstall it, I always get nothing. It seems there are some information retained in the registry.  Is there any tools can help me to find them out and solve this problem ?

By the way, I used vsto | local to install my office add in.
And I have completed all the added registry in my uninstaller, but seems not work

Comment: So, just to clarify: you install your addin, test it, it works correctly, you uninstall it, then reinstall it, and at that point the addin no longer executes? Or what specifically doesn't work?

Comment: I just can not find the addin ...

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot find it"?

Comment: Mean, even though you reinstall the office add-in, it can not work properly, it just gone, you can not find it any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than programmatically trying to uninstall, do it the old fashioned way. Remove the add-in via office, let it remove the keys and such, and then try again.

I believe an add-in is saved to:

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{guid}\addin-name\keys
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\addinName
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\product\Addins\addinName (all users entry)
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\product\Addins\addinName (current user entry)

and, depending on the system, the Wow6432Node as well under HKLM &/or HKCU

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the click-once cache sometimes hangs on to these old versions and won't let you re-install. You can try a couple of things:
1) run the utility from MS called Mage. You want to run "Mage -cc" which clears the cache.
2) if that doesn't work you can add the environment variable: VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS and set itto 0. Try the process again. This will give you a more detailed pop-up of information.